# htaccess two endpoints showing same

Tags: .htaccess

I have two endpoints on my website `/i/` snd `/a/`. They do show different information, but both the same. Currently, I have the `/i/` working like so..

`/i/1234`5 (where 12345 is the itemId).

`/a/67890` (where 67890 is the itemId that is active).

If I goto `/a/67890`, itll show the `/i/` UI, not the `/a/` UI. Here is my `.htaaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?hostname\.app
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.hostname.app/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /i/index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /results/index.php?/$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /a/index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

What am I doing wrong? It looks like `/a/` is being routed to `/i/`.

Comment: What URLs should be handled by `/results/index.php?/$1`?

Comment: thats specific to that endpoint. /results/ is seperate. the results page handles the i and the a. dependings what is view inside of the results page, itll route to /i or /a.

Comment: _“What am I doing wrong?”_ - you are simply matching things in the wrong order, resp. too broadly. _Of course_ `^(.*)$` matches `a/67890`, how can that be surprising …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?hostname\.app$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([ia])/(.*)$ $1/index.php?id=$2 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(results)/(.*)$ $1/index.php?/$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: THANK YOU! Worked like a charm. Can you recommend any reading on htaccess? Its the one thing I *always* struggle on!